# Configuring OpenVPN to use Firewalld instead of iptables on Centos 7

Tags: centos, iptables, openvpn, firewalld

I need to configure  OpenVPN on Centos 7 using `firewalld`.

I used iptables on Centos 6.5 and only had to add the following lines to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s "10.0.0.0/24" -o "wlan0" -j MASQUERADE 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT 
run the command: echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
open port 443.
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `firewall-cmd` command.

Assuming you're opening the firewall up to OpenVPN on the default zone, carry out the following commands.  If you are running it on a non-default zone, then add `--zone=<zone>` to the commands.

Note: If you use default `public` zone for your external facing network adapter then your loopback interface could also be masqueraded (dependant on the version of `firewalld` you're running) which can cause issues if you are running a service (such as mySQL) that is accessed locally.

First, list what's currently open:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-services
http https ssh
```

Next, add the `openvpn` service:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-service openvpn
success
```

A quick check:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-services
http https openvpn ssh
```

The above will allow `openvpn` to work, which you can now test.  However, it won't last over restarts.  To make it permanent, add the `--permanent` option:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service openvpn`
success
```

Note that this last command doesn't open the port until the next restart, so you need to use both commands.

Finally, add the masquerade:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-masquerade
success
```

And make it permanent after a restart:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade
success
```

Confirm it:

```
# firewall-cmd --query-masquerade
yes
```

Note that if your incoming OpenVPN connection is in a different zone to your Internet facing connection the masquerade should be on the latter and you'll need to use the `--zone=<zone>` option with the `--add-masquerade` commands.

Comment: How do you tell what the definition of the openvpn service is in firewalld? For example, how can you verify that it's allowing openvpn over TCP 443?

Comment: @Christopher - Service files are located in `/lib/firewalld/services/`.  In your case, it will be `openvpn.xml` within that directory.  User defined services go in `/etc/firewalld/services`.  Note that the default port for openvpn is `UDP/1194`.

Comment: Thanks. I was having a problem, and thought it might be firewalld. The only thing I did differently from the above instructions was use "https" instead of "openvpn" as the service name to add. Turns out, it wasn't firewalld with the problem. I was just being dumb, and forgot to configure my client properly to use "tun" instead of "tap". The above instructions work perfectly.

Comment: I've noticed a problem with adding masquerade to the entire zone. This tries to NAT my connections to the loopback interface, when I am running other services on localhost. I'd like to limit the masquerading to just 10.8.0.0/16. Any idea how you might do that?

Comment: [This bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=904098) may be the cause.  Basically, if your default zone is the `public` zone then it masquerades the loopback interface.  It turns out that I'd previously set my default zone to be `external`, so never faced the issue you're seeing.  Try moving the services and the adapter to another zone to see if that helps.  Let me know :-)

Comment: Would moving the interfaces to a non-default zone be essentially the equivalent to explicitly moving them into the public zone? I assume eth0 and tun0 should be in the zone doing the masquerading, but where do I put lo?

Comment: On my setup, I have `eth0` in `external` with the `openvpn` service and masquerade enabled, and `tun0` in `internal`.  When I run `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` there's no mention of `lo`.

Comment: I'm not sure the pros and cons, but I seemed to get things to work by putting eth0 and tun0 in public (or external... same config, didn't matter) and lo in trusted. I think the main thing is that lo can't be in the masqueraded zone, and unless specified it's in the default zone, so the others need to be moved out of the default zone explicitly??? Bleh, this is so bothersome. Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: @garethTheRed I have a similar issue.  Are you willing to take a look?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290046/openvpn-server-does-not-reply-to-client-ping

Comment: @garethTheRed I was running firewalld 0.3.9.x and the masquerade was interfering with loopback, so nginx was having errors to redirect to my local path and showing the websites. Updating firewalld did the trick, after hours of research, you saved me.

Comment: @garethTheRed, I believe I'm having the same issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/915257/ssh-port-forwarding-with-firewall-cmd can you take a look please ?