# How do I masquerade only a specific subnet with firewalld?

Tags: centos, openvpn, firewalld

I'm running [openvpn on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7) with [firewalld](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149193/118916). I've enabled masquerading on the public (default) zone, and it works fine. However, I occasionally need to run services on localhost/127.0.0.1, and the masquerading is messing that up. The services properly bind to 127.0.0.1, but the client code which tries to connect to it seems to be mapping the destination IP address of 127.0.0.1 to the IP address for eth0, where the server is not listening (it was configured for 127.0.0.1 only).

How do I limit the masquerading to only a specific subnet so openvpn still works, but I can also access services locally on localhost without masquerading interfering?

Another way to word my question: How do I prevent masquerading of the loopback address(es)?

Some ideas I've had, but can't figure out how to do (or do without breaking something else):

- Limit masquerading to only 10.8.0.0/16 for openvpn
- Limit masquerading by moving the IP address for eth0 to another zone
- Tolerate masquerading by moving the loopback interface to the trusted zone, and adding the IP address for eth0 as a source in the trusted zone

Comment: This bug may be related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=904098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
external
  interfaces: eth0
  masquerade: yes

internal
  interfaces: tun0
  masquerade: no

public (default)
  interfaces:      # not used
  masquerade: no

trusted
  interfaces: lo
  masquerade: no
```

For this to work, I had to explicitly declare that `lo` was in the `trusted` zone, `tun0` was in the `internal` zone, and `eth0` was in the `external` zone. To do that, I used (for example):

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=external --add-interface=eth0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-interface=tun0
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted  --add-interface=lo
firewall-cmd --reload
```

For `eth0`, it was also necessary to add `ZONE="external"` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` for it to continue to work across reboots. This wasn't necessary for the other interfaces.

The actual services/ports open in the `trusted` and `internal` zone, I left to their defaults. I made sure the default zone (`public`) had ssh on it (which is default) for emergencies (like if an update renames the `eth0` interface) and added the services I want to expose to the `external` zone.

`masquerade` was already on by default in the `external` zone, and off in the others.

This setup works with **firewalld-0.3.9-14.el7.noarch**
I'm not sure why putting them in separate zones was necessary for it to exclude the loopback interface from masquerading (turning masquerading on sets the rule: `-A POST_external_allow ! -i lo -j MASQUERADE`, which looks sufficient to me, but I'm no expert). However, I found [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=904098) which might be related and the issue could be fixed in future versions.